# Google Signin not work in ios release mode react native

Tags: react-native, google-signin, react-native-ios

My google signin ios not work after choose user in release mode, but in development mode its work very well, any suggestion?

this is my dependencies:
"react-native": "0.57.1",
"react-native-google-signin": "^1.0.0-rc7",

thanks

Answer (score 0):

finally in found this answer, you must put:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

in your info.infoPlist to run in release mode on ios